# How do I enter Canadian tax info from US form 1042-S and record captial gains from cashing in stock options?

Tags: stocks, taxes, canada, employee-stock-options

I am assuming these issues are related. I am working in Canada for a US company. I buy stock options every quarter. In 2011 I cashed in some stock options and received the cash.

How do I enter the amount of received cash in my Canadian tax return?
Does it matter the cash came from an employee stock option?

I also received form 1042-S from the US company that handles the stocks. It lists a Gross Income of $77 (box 2), a tax rate of %15 (box 5), and Federal tax withheld of $12 (box 7).

Where, if anywhere do I record this in my tax return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give you a specific answer because I'm not a tax accountant, so you should *seek advice from a tax professional with experience relevant to your situation*. This could be a complicated situation. That being said, one place you could start is the Canada Revenue Agency's [statement](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/rprtng-ncm/lns101-170/121/menu-eng.html) on investment income, which contains this paragraph:

> Interest, foreign interest and dividend income, foreign income,
>   foreign non-business income, and certain other income are all amounts
>   you report on your return. They are usually shown on the following
>   slips: T5, T3, T5013, T5013A

To avoid double taxation, Canada and the US almost certainly have a foreign tax treaty that ensures you are only taxed in your country of residence. I'm assuming you're a resident of Canada.

Also, [this page](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/rprtng-ncm/lns101-170/121/frgn-eng.html) states that:

> If you received foreign interest or dividend income, you have to
>   report it in Canadian dollars. Use the [Bank of Canada](http://www.bankofcanada.ca/) exchange rate
>   that was in effect on the day you received the income. If you received
>   the income at different times during the year, use the [average annual
>   exchange rate.](http://www.bankofcanada.ca/en/rates/exchange_avg_pdf.html)

**You should consult a tax professional.** I'm not a tax professional, let alone one who specializes in the Canadian tax system. A professional is the *only* one you should trust to answer your question with 100% accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts in this 1042-S form. The income/dividends go into the Canada T5 form. There will be credit if 1042-S has held money already, so use T2209 to report too.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what software you use. It has to be reported as a foreign income and you can claim foreign tax paid as a foreign tax credit.